# How to copy the contents of NSMutableArray to another NStArray in iphone app?

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have two array one is NSMutableArray and one is NSArray i want to store the contents of NSMutableArray in NSArray but it is not working for me gives exception unrecognised selector sent.

```
myArray=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:appDelegate.surveyAnswersScreenOne];
```

Note, `SurveyAnswerScreenOne` is an `NSMutableArray`

Comment: Are you sure unrecognised selector is coming because of this. put a break point to check again the point of crash.

Comment: check appDelegate has reference and NSlog appDelegate.surveyAnswersScreenOne if appDelegate.surveyAnswersScreenOne has value then myArray=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[appDelegate.surveyAnswersScreenOne copy]];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in many ways -

```
NSArray * myArray = [appDelegate.surveyAnswersScreenOne copy];

NSArray * myArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:appDelegate.surveyAnswersScreenOne];

NSArray * myArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:appDelegate.surveyAnswersScreenOne];
```

But first of all your `appDelegate.surveyAnswersScreenOne` should have objects in it.

Comment: Not possible ! First try to print your appDelegate.surveyAnswersScreenOne array... You said appDelegate.surveyAnswersScreenOne is a mutableArray.

Comment: NSMutableArray*surveyAnswersScreenOne i am declaring like this in appDelegate

Comment: How you make your appdelegate object ? This should be declare as appDelegate = (Appdelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

Comment: Actually, NSMutableArray is a subclass of NSArray. I believe you can initiate an array with it. Pretty sure I have many times. Create mutable, massage contents and pass off immutable made from mutable. Fairly common practice.

Comment: yes thanks i am checking problem is in NSMutableArray it is empty i think

Comment: Empty wouldn't be an issue, nil may be.

Comment: @DeanDavids - Empty would be an issue in this case because if his array is empty the other also would be empty and then he would think that there is any mistake in copy or init method while problem is with NSMutableArray ...

Comment: none of these is working i have now fixed my nsmutablearray but your code not workinh

Comment: Oh Great! above code is not working okay i accept this if some one says that except you......You can test it with a separate sample... then let me know it is working or not ?

Comment: @Abizern - Thanks I have changed my answer now :) But for **Nazia Jan** nothing is working ... we all're wrong for her....

Answer (score 0):

From what we see here, it is most likely that your mutable array is nil. Look into the creation of that in you app delegate. If it is created properly, check that it is retained. Is it a strong reference?

```
@propery(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *surveyAnswersScreenOne;
```

for one, I would use the convenience method:

```
myArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:appDelegate.surveyAnswersScreenOne];
```

If surveyAnswersScreenOne is a valid array, mutable or otherwise, this should work. Try printing it to the console to be sure. This will return empty array if surveyAnswersScreenOne is nil, where alloc initWithArray will fail.
Check you mutable array like this.

```
NSLog(@"Mutable array is %@", appDelegate.surveyAnswersScreenOne);
```

Comment: yes i have checked but not working for me i don't know why it is so

Comment: Did you put that NSLog in. You need to step back through and make sure your objects are all valid. We'll need to see more of your code and you need to locate more precisely where the exception occurs. Set a breakpoint before creating the array and then step through to see precisely which call is falling down.

Comment: exception occure while coppying array

Comment: Did you try my suggestions? Is your MutableArray a valid array? Did you try using the convenience method in place of what you have?

Answer (score 0):

**Have you made object for your `appDelegate` ?**

```
appDelegate = (yourDelegateClass *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
```

If yes, then other answers should work!

```
myArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:appDelegate.surveyAnswersScreenOne];
```